# Anyone remember a short story from the '70's that had some alien food or drink connoisseurs, one of which was named Demi Tasse?

Tags: story-identification, aliens, food

I remember they were aliens, maybe Martians, and I think there were three of them, and they ended up talking to some kids when they landed. I can only remember that one of them was called Demi Tasse...pretty sure the other two had names that were food or drink related as well.